# Ignore unknown properties in python suds soap client

Tags: python, web-services, soap, wsdl, suds

How do i configure python suds client to ignore unknown properties in a SOAP response that are not present in the wsdl?

For example, if the input wsdl contains an object like this

```
  <complexType name="VolCreateAttr">
   <sequence>
     <element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
     <element name="description" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
     <element name="size" type="xsd:unsignedLong" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
   </sequence>
  </complexType>
```

and i make a SOAP call getVolInfo that returns an object of the above type. But the response has an extra property called "reserve" in addition to the 3 properties mentioned in the wsdl. Currently suds throw a **Type not found** error. How do i configure suds to ignore unknown properties in the response

Answer (score 0):

I think there are basically two options which are about either tweaking the WSDL so it matches the real return values or removing the extra elements directly from the output:

- write a [DocumentPlugin](https://bitbucket.org/jurko/suds/src/1871530805fd42670e159f630d1293df093d26e7/suds/plugin.py?at=default#cl-91) to change the WSDL
- write a [MessagePlugin](https://bitbucket.org/jurko/suds/src/1871530805fd42670e159f630d1293df093d26e7/suds/plugin.py?at=default#cl-121) to change the response.

Alternatively you could use a different SOAP library which generates code from a WSDL and tweak that code by hand.

Comment: There is no simple setting which tells to ignore unknown members in response?